# Running an extensive PHP script - writes XML

Tags: php, ssh

I have quite an extensive  PHP script that I have to run on my database as well as gather img sizes from the file structure and write that information to an XML file. I have tried running directly from the web browser with minimum success as the Gateway times out after about 3 minutes. I have tries running from an ssh shell as well with no success. here is most of the script

```
    //Get all galleries from client
            $query = mysql_query("SELECT *
                                    FROM gallery
                                    WHERE clientRef BETWEEN 420
                                    AND 430
                                    ORDER BY clientRef
                                ");

            while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)) {

            //set gallery id

            $galleryID =  $row['id'];
            $clientRef = $row['clientRef'];
        //Check image sizes and set horizontal vs vertical
            $fImageSizeName = mysql_fetch_array($qAlbumImages);
            $imageSizeName = $fImageSizeName['OrgImageName'];

            $galleryPath = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . "/data/gallery/" . $galleryID . "/images/"; 

            if(is_dir($galleryPath)) {
                list($width, $height) = getimagesize($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . "/data/gallery/" . $galleryID . "/images/album/" . $imageSizeName);

    header("Content-Type: text/plain");


        //Create the xml document
        $xmlDoc = new DOMDocument();

        //Create the root Element
        $root = $xmlDoc->appendChild(
                $xmlDoc->createElement("PageflipDataSet"));
        //Create settings element
        $settings = $root->appendChild(
                    $xmlDoc->createElement("Settings"));
    //Create PageOrder Node
        $PageOrder = $root->appendChild(
                    $xmlDoc->createElement("PageOrder"));

        $qAlbumImages = mysql_query("   SELECT *
                                        FROM galleryimage 
                                        WHERE galleryId='{$galleryID}' 
                                        AND clientRef= '{$clientRef}' 
                                        ORDER BY sort
                                    ");

        while ($fAlbumImages = mysql_fetch_array($qAlbumImages)) {
            $path  = "../../../../data/gallery/" . $galleryID . "/images/album/" . $fAlbumImages['OrgImageName'];
            //Create the PageData Node
            $PageData = $PageOrder->appendChild(
                        $xmlDoc->createElement("PageData"));
                //PageFile attribute
                $PageData->appendChild(
                        $xmlDoc->createAttribute("PageFile"))->appendChild(
                        $xmlDoc->createTextNode($path));
        }//close while

//Format output so it looks pretty
    $xmlDoc->formatOutput = true;
    //Save and create path to gallery ID

    $galleryPath = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . "/data/gallery/" . $galleryID;

    //Set path
    if(is_dir($galleryPath)) {
        $xmlPath = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/data/gallery/' . $galleryID . '/xml/pageflipdata.xml';
        $xmlDoc->save($xmlPath);
    }
}//close while
```

Any suggestions on how I should go about doing this. There are about 2000 clientRef and each of the clientRef have 5-10 albums which can contain 15-30 images.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If timeout is the primary issue, you could just do it in smaller chunks and combine the xml later manually.

If this needs to run regularly, you can use a similar process but run each 'smaller chunk' in a different request using ajax or something to wait for confirmation from all the small chunk scripts to run an xml combination script.

Of course simply increasing the max_execution_time of PHP would be easier. If you don't have access to this, you might be able to tweak something into working order by monitoring execution time and then calling [set-time-limit](http://php.net/manual/en/function.set-time-limit.php) to reset the timer again. I've never tried this, though, so just an idea.